# Why does Eclipse breakpoint filtering not find my class?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am filtering my breakpoint on IllegalArgumentException.  I'd like to exclude a class, CoverageTypeEnum, in my project.  When I attempt to add a class (I click add class, then start typing the name of my class) to my filter CoverageTypeEnum is not available in the list.  This class is in another package outside where my breakpoint is.  Why is my class missing?

[image: description1]
[image: description2]

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're doing. What do you mean by "filtering my breakpoint" and "exclude a class?"

Comment: He's making an "exception breakpoint", and it has options for "restrict to selected location(s)" which includes a button for "Add Class...".  I don't know why it wouldn't work.  If you enter control-alt-T and start typing the name of your class, does it show up there?  That would tell us for sure it is in your workspace and therefore known to eclipse.

Comment: Yes, the CoverageTypeEnum class does show up when I search in the Open Type window.

Comment: Is CoverageTypeEnum in a separate project?  Is it your own class?  Does any class from that project show up?  from that package in that project?  Is it an actual class, not an interface (yes I know it's named ...Enum, but need to check...)

Comment: CoverageTypeEnum is in the same project.  It is my own class, not an interface.  It is an Enum type.  Yes, some other classes from my project do show up in the search list.  My class is in a different package than where the breakpoint is set.  It is in a different package than where the test code is being run.